# Rails AASM; How to do some action if the specific transition is occured

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aasm

I use state machine gem called [AASM](https://github.com/aasm/aasm) on rails.

There are an event which has two types of transitions.

Three three types of state

```
state pending
state past_due
state paid
```

`pending` can be changed into `paid`
`past_due` can be changed into `paid`

```
  event :pay do
      transitions from: [:pending, :past_due], to: :paid
  end
```

So here I'd love to do some action only if `past_due` goes `paid`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to define transitions in two separate statements:

```
event :pay do
  transitions from: :pending, to: :paid
  transitions from: :past_due, to: :paid, after: :do_your_custom_action
end
```

See more about callbacks [in the docs](https://github.com/aasm/aasm#callbacks).

Comment: Actually, using symbol in `transitions from: :past_due, to: :paid, after: :do_your_custom_action`  do not work for me. Method `do_your_custom_action` is not called.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I was using `before:` not `after:`. `after:` works with symbol. There is no transition`before:` callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the `after` callback to both the transition and the event.

Since the event is same for both transitions you should attach the callback to the specific transition that is from `past_due` to `paid`.

As you are covering both flows in a single transition, first step would be to make a separate transition for this flow and attach the callback to it. As,

```
transitions :from => :past_due, :to => :paid, :after => your_required_action
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I pass a block to the `after` callback

```
event :pay do
  after do
    # do_something
  end
  transitions from: [:pending, :past_due], to: :paid
end
```

This way I ensure that `do_something` will be executed after the `event :pay` finished.

Another way is attach the callback to a `transitions`, where the callback will be executed after the transitions is finished.

Please, take a look to the docs and [read about callbacks](https://github.com/aasm/aasm#callbacks) and its order of calling to cover your needs